# NameError: name 'variable' is not defined. Already declared variable but still error

Tags: python, csv, variables, text-files, nameerror

I tried to extract data from a text file (cisco switch logs) and convert it to CSV so I can create a table and sort out the data & create graphs out of it. So here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
import glob
import sys

pathh = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Taffy R. Mantang\\Desktop\\PR logs\\*\\")
#This part of the code opens all the text with the name ISW-1.txt inside the PR logs folder
for x in pathh:
    # Detect the line number in text file to know where the row begin
    phrase = "Shelf Panel CPUID Power CPU(5s) CPU(1m) CPU(5m) Peak PhyMem FreeMem Mem"
    file = open("{0}".format(x) + "\\ISW-1.txt")

    for number, line in enumerate(file):
        if phrase in line:
            sh_pro = number
            break
        file.close()
    #Convert the text file to CSV from the row determined earlier
    with open("{0}".format(x) + '\\ISW-1.txt', 'r') as rf:
        r = csv.reader(rf, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' ')
        rows = list(r)

    heada = rows[sh_pro]
    heada.insert(0, " ")
    print(heada)
    #to mark the last row
    skipprocessor = sh_pro + 4
   
    for i in range(7):
        if i == 0:
            print(rows[skipprocessor + i])
        if i == 2:
            sub_heada = rows[skipprocessor + i]
            sub_heada.insert(0, " ")
            sub_heada.insert(1, " ")
            sub_heada.insert(2, " ")
            print(rows[skipprocessor + i])
        if i == 4:
            sub_heada = rows[skipprocessor + i]
            sub_heada.insert(0, " ")
            sub_heada.insert(1, " ")
            sub_heada.insert(2, " ")
            print(rows[skipprocessor + i])
        if i == 6:
            sub_heada = rows[skipprocessor + i]
            sub_heada.insert(0, " ")
            sub_heada.insert(1, " ")
            sub_heada.insert(2, " ")
            print(rows[skipprocessor + i])
```

Previously it worked and it printed the output successfully. However while I was experimenting with exporting the output to an excel table, suddenly there was an error saying:

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Taffy R. Mantang\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 26, in 
heada = rows[sh_pro]
NameError: name 'sh_pro' is not defined

---

I traced back and undo everything but it still gives the same error.

I tried to remove an indent on line 26, it managed to print(heada). but messed up the if else code down below it and not print out the rest below.

What exactly is the problem? Help :'''((

Comment: If the phrase isn't found, you never set `sh_pro`.

Answer (score 0):

`sh_pro` is not defined because you are not hitting the condition `if phrase in line:`, I would suggest:

```
for number, line in enumerate(file):
        if phrase in line:
            sh_pro = number
            break
        file.close()
    #Convert the text file to CSV from the row determined earlier
    with open("{0}".format(x) + '\\ISW-1.txt', 'r') as rf:
        r = csv.reader(rf, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' ')
        rows = list(r)
    try:
        heada = rows[sh_pro]
    except NameError:
        # error handling
```

Comment: Did you fill the code where you do your error handling? Can you show the error message traceback?

Answer (score 0):

In order to declare **sh_pro**, the condition `if phrase in line:` in your **for cycle** should return **True**. So if your condition returns **False** then your interpreter never meets such name as **sh_pro**. You can try to modify your code in a way that **sh_pro** is declared before you want to start working with it.

```
for number, line in enumerate(file):
        if phrase in line:
            sh_pro = number
            break
        file.close()
```